# How to disable Content Security Policy in Android WebView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to load TikTok website in WebView. But I can't. In logcat I got this error:

```
"[Report Only] Refused to load the script 'https://sf16-scmcdn-va.ibytedtos.com/goofy/slardar/fe/sdk/plugins/monitors.3.5.4.maliva.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' polyfill.io *.kakao.com *.cdn-apple.com *.tiktokcdn.com *.byteoversea.com *.tiktok.com".
", source: https://www.tiktok.com/ (0)
```

Seems Chromium blocking some javascript files that's why I got white screen. How can I disable  or any solutions for it?

**My Webview:**

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewWebClient());
    webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(System.getProperty("http.agent"));
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.tiktok.com/");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Fixed it. Thanks all.

Comment: not working for me.   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to load the script 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-168887836-1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.